# Magento2 success/error message not showing

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom module and added pagination in the view file after adding any message from the controller it's not showing:

Controller file

```
<?php

namespace Geekay\DigitalVendors\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
class Generate extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_customerSession;  
    protected $_validationHelper;  
    protected $_messageManager;  
    protected $request;  
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Geekay\DigitalVendors\Helper\Validation $validation,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request, 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) 
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_validationHelper = $validation;
        $this->_messageManager  = $messageManager;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }
    public function execute()
    {
        if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
           $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
        } 
        $orderid = $this->getRequest() ->getParam('orderid');
        $validationResult = $this->_validationHelper->frontEndValidation($orderid);
        if(isset($validationResult['status'])){
            if($validationResult['status'] == 'error'){
                $this->_messageManager->addError($validationResult['message']);
            } else {
                $this->_messageManager->addSuccess($validationResult['message']);             
            }
        }       
        return $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl()); 
    }
}
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Geekay\DigitalVendors\Block\Index\Index" 
                name="digital_orders_list" 
                template="digital_orders.phtml" 
                cacheable="false">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Block

```
<?php

namespace Geekay\DigitalVendors\Block\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $orders;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $objectManager;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) 
    {
         parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->objectManager   = $objectManager;
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {         
        parent::_prepareLayout();      
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Digital Downloads')); 
        if ($this->getOrders()) 
        {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','apr.digi.pager')
                    ->setAvailableLimit(array(10=>10,20=>20,50=>50))
                    ->setShowPerPage(true)
                    ->setCollection($this->getOrders());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getOrders()->load();
        }
       return $this;
    }   
    public function getOrders()
    {

        if (!$this->orders) {            
            $page       =   ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
            $pageSize   =   ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 1;
            $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
            
            /* Get Digital enabled orders only */
            $orderList = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => ['complete','processing','myfatoorah_processed']]);
            $ids = [];
            foreach ($orderList as  $_order) 
            { 
                foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $item) 
                {
                    $product = $item->getProduct();
                    if($product->getDigitalEnable()==1){
                        array_push($ids,$_order->getId());
                    }
                }       
            } 
            $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' =>$ids])
                    ->setOrder('created_at','desc')
                    ->setPageSize($pageSize)
                    ->setCurPage($page);
        }
        return $this->orders;
    } 
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    public function getBaseUrl(){
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }  
    

}
```

Comment: hello dear, you want my account page custom link and this click then open order related custom grid. so am i right.?

Comment: @mohitvamja Grid is fine, There is a function to generate code against the order, and controller throw message based on condition and those message are not showing on this custom page

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
namespace Geekay\DigitalVendors\Controller\Index;

class Generate extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_validationHelper;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Geekay\DigitalVendors\Helper\Validation $validation
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_validationHelper = $validation;
        $this->_messageManager  = $messageManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try
        {
            if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn())
            {
                $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
            }

            $orderid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('orderid');
            $validationResult = $this->_validationHelper->frontEndValidation($orderid);

            if(isset($validationResult['status']))
            {
                if($validationResult['status'] == 'error')
                {
                    $this->_messageManager->addError($validationResult['message']);
                } else {
                    $this->_messageManager->addSuccess($validationResult['message']);
                }
            }
            $this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Something Wen't Wrong.'));
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            $this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('An unspecified error occurred.'));
        }
        return $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```